# Prototype scoped bean with conditional annotation

Tags: java, spring

I try to reload a bean on every request with a potentially different implementation.

In my controller, I retrieve each time the bean from ApplicationContext :

```
@Controller
public class LabelsController implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @RequestMapping("/...")
    public ModelAndView labelConcerns()  {
        System.out.println("Here I ask for a fresh bean");
        InconsistentCaseDetector inconsistentCaseDetector = applicationContext.getBean(InconsistentCaseDetector.class);
```

InconsistentCaseDetector is a raw interface. I have several implementations annotated as follows (with different conditions):

```
@Component
@Conditional(SkosFormatSelected.class)
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class InconsistentCaseDetectorImpl implements InconsistentCaseDetector {
...
```

An example of a condition :

```
public class SkosFormatSelected implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        System.out.println("Is skos format selected ?");
        return Formats.getCurrent().equals(Formats.SKOS);
    }
```

But the `matches` methods of the condition classes are only invocated at startup.
During startup the log instructions ("Is skos format selected ?", "Is xml format selected ?"...) are displayed and then this :

```
org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner  - Identified candidate component class: file [/home/..../.../WEB-INF/classes/tests/model/vocabulary/skos/algorithm/InconsistentCaseDetectorImpl.class]
```

But then, at each request, the conditions are no longer executed and it is always the same implementation that is served. 
Here's what logs show at runtime :

```
Here I ask for a fresh bean
163326 [http-nio-8080-exec-23] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'inconsistentCaseDetectorImpl'
...
163328 [http-nio-8080-exec-23] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.inconsistentCaseDetectorImpl'
163329 [http-nio-8080-exec-23] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Finished creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.inconsistentCaseDetectorImpl'
```

So when I request the bean, it returns an instance from the cache instead of creating a new one. And later, but I do not know where, it seems to create a new one, still without executing the conditional clause.

Comment: Can something notated `@Component` and thus intended for autowiring also be prototype scope? If it gets autowired isn't that going to happen at initialization time?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html) : "When used as a type-level annotation in conjunction with Component, Scope indicates the name of a scope to use for instances of the annotated type. "

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Autowired
@RequestMapping("/...")
public ModelAndView labelConcerns(final InconsistentCaseDetector inconsistentCaseDetector)  {
    ...
}
```

should work.

By the way,

1. you should move the `@Component` to the interface (DRY/SRP), maybe the `@Scope` too.
2. you should inject the `ApplicationContext` instead of using the interface `ApplicationContextAware` (DIP)

Comment: I turned my local variable into method parameter as you recommended. Now I get an exception at runtime : org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [...InconsistentCaseDetector]: Specified class is an interface
. org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:99)

Comment: And if I move `@Component` up to the interface, i get this exception during startup : org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'labelsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'labelConcerns' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '...InconsistentCaseDetector' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Comment: @Jdpro Ok, what version of Spring CDI are you using?

Comment: I use version 4.3.4.RELEASE for all spring components.